# Error on Google App Engine Python 502 Bad

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, gunicorn

```
{
  "textPayload": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py\", line 589, in spawn_worker\n    worker.init_process()\n  File \"/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py\", line 134, in init_process\n    self.load_wsgi()\n  File \"/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py\", line 146, in load_wsgi\n    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()\n  File \"/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py\", line 67, in wsgi\n    self.callable = self.load()\n  File \"/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py\", line 58, in load\n    return self.load_wsgiapp()\n  File \"/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py\", line 48, in load_wsgiapp\n    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)\n  File \"/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py\", line 359, in import_app\n    mod = importlib.import_module(module)\n  File \"/layers/google.python.runtime/python/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py\", line 127, in import_module\n    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)\n  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 1014, in _gcd_import\n  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 991, in _find_and_load\n  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked\n  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 671, in _load_unlocked\n  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>\", line 843, in exec_module\n  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed\n  File \"/workspace/main.py\", line 4, in <module>\n    from google.cloud import datastore\n  File \"/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore/__init__.py\", line 59, in <module>\n    from google.cloud.datastore.batch import Batch\n  File \"/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore/batch.py\", line 24, in <module>\n    from google.cloud.datastore import helpers\n  File \"/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore/helpers.py\", line 31, in <module>\n    from google.cloud.datastore.key import Key\n  File \"/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore/key.py\", line 23, in <module>\n    from google.cloud.datastore import _app_engine_key_pb2\n  File \"/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore/_app_engine_key_pb2.py\", line 36, in <module>\n    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(\n  File \"/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/protobuf/descriptor.py\", line 561, in __new__\n    _message.Message._CheckCalledFromGeneratedFile()\nTypeError: Descriptors cannot not be created directly.",
  "insertId": "6497b47c000cd9fbde0bc239",
  "resource": {
    "type": "gae_app",
    "labels": {
      "module_id": "default",
      "zone": "europe-west2-2",
      "project_id": "onebillapp",
      "version_id": "20230625t032643"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2023-06-25T03:29:00.842235Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "labels": {
    "clone_id": "00c61b117c32448c06918e5fe8f87a4c5feb7868de8605f19cbc47eb36899e62d3be7558abfd3a2f7a3d7e2f5e7527fdb7bd53e834ef"
  },
  "logName": "projects/onebillapp/logs/stderr",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2023-06-25T03:29:00.884781358Z"
}
```

app.yml

runtime: python38

entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app --timeout 90

handlers:

- url : /static
  static_dir : static
- url : /.*
  script : auto

Could you please help what I am missing why I can not deploy the app ?